# Plotting a function in R where the input is of length 3

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a function I have defined in terms of a parameter x and plot the function over three values of x.  I get an error about the lengths being different.

The length of the function is 1 while x is 3.

```
l <- seq(0, 7)
p <- c(5, 2, 9, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0)
loglikGeo <- function(beta){sum(p*log(dgeom(l, beta)))}
beta <- seq(0.01, 0.40, 0.01)
plot(beta, loglikGeo)
```

What is going on?

Comment: There are a couple of issues.  1. You define `loglikGeo` as a function with one argument, but you don't call it with an argument inside `plot()`.  Try `loglikeGeo(beta)`, or even just define the function with no argument and then call `loglikGeo()`, since you rely on globally-scoped variables inside the function anyway. 2. You return a single scalar value (a sum) from `loglikGeo`.  That's why you don't have the same length as `beta`, which is why `plot` throws an error.

Comment: Point #1 I understand.  I added the (beta) argument and changed the first argument of plot to 0.02 as a test and it plotted. I am not sure what globally scoped means.  For point #2 I am trying to create a function of beta and then pass in those different values of beta and see it on a graph.  So the sum should be a function of beta.  It should not be like plug in all the beta's and then sum.

Comment: By global I mean that you refer to `p` and `l` inside your function definition, but they aren't passed into your function.  So you are relying on R to know that, outside of the scope of what goes on inside `loglikGeo()`, there are variables you've defined that you want to make use of.  As opposed to creating the function with three arguments, like: `loglikGeo <- function(beta, l, p) {...}`.  As for the final output, `sapply` works, you can also use `purrr::map_dbl`, which is the tidyverse approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loglikGeo` is defined as a function in your code so you cannot give it as as argument to plot. You need a vector in your y-argument in `plot()`. 
To apply a function to each element of a vector and return a vector of function values you can use `sapply(vector,function)`. Replace the last line in your code with:

```
loglikGeo_values <- sapply(beta,loglikGeo)
plot(beta, loklikGeo_values)
```

Comment: Ah.  This is it.  Thank you.